# Magento2 - What is the best way to remove and add an image in magento using rest API?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload, gallery-image

For an `SKU`, I have multiple `images`. Every time I change something related to the `SKU`, I do a PUT. But before that I also DELETE the images using in a loop

```
https://<magentoInstance>/rest/all/V1/products/<mySKU>/media/<imageIDs>
```

Only the first image is getting deleted in this way.

For others the API is giving me `"Product cannot be saved... "` and does not delete.

So what is the best way to `DELETE (all the images)` and then `POST new images.` I PUT the product and then POST the images. Is this correct? Will there be any caching issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all images by `POST`ing the product with an empty `media_gallery_entries` key:

```
{"sku": sku, "media_gallery_entries": []}
```

You can add new ones by using the same call with a non-empty `media_gallery_entries` key:

```
{"sku": sku, "media_gallery_entries": [...]}
```

Comment: Thank you @bfontaine.This is what I ended up doing.